# 'Truncated incorrect INTEGER value' Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting `Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'D'` warning while I try to run the following query:

```
UPDATE MESSAGES
SET status = CASE
    WHEN 
    (from_id='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'S'
    WHEN 
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'R'
    WHEN 
    ((from_id  ='111111111' AND status='R') OR
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='S')) THEN 'D'
    END
WHERE primary_key = '236499681204'
AND
    (CASE
    WHEN 
    (from_id='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'S'
    WHEN 
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'R'
    WHEN 
    ((from_id  ='111111111' AND status='R') OR
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='S')) THEN 'D'
    END) is not null
```

I have read the posts [MySQL 'Truncated incorrect INTEGER value'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946899/mysql-truncated-incorrect-integer-value) and [MYSQL Truncated incorrect INTEGER value error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195235/mysql-truncated-incorrect-integer-value-error). But they dont apply to my case. Here, `status` is of type `VARCHAR(1)`.

Is there something I'm missing?

**Edit**

Here's the query for creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `MESSAGES` (
  `primary_key` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_id` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `to_id` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`primary_key`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=123456789876 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Please help :(

Comment: Hello again :). How did you  define `primary_key` field?

Comment: Please show your table definition

Comment: what is `from_id` and `to_id`?

Comment: `primary_key` is of the type `BIGINT(12)`

Comment: @juergend Please look at my edit and help. I'm kinda stuck. cant find anything elsewhere

Comment: Doesn't appear that you are comparing the case statements to anything after your `AND` ... '`D IS NOT NULL`' makes no sense.

Comment: i'm doing `CASE(...) is not null`

Comment: `'236499681204'` is a character literal. Do **not** use it to compare numbers. Numbers do **not** need quotes. Never rely on implicit data conversion - use proper literals (only use single quotes for character values).

Comment: I'm using a `NamedParameterJDBCQuery` and need to pass that. I cant store such a value in `int`. So I store it as a `String` :( Is there a better way?
Besides, the error clearly says `incorrect INTEGER value: 'D'` and that means it's something wrong with `status`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is not because of `status` but because of the comparison

```
(CASE
    WHEN 
    (from_id='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'S'
    WHEN 
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'R'
    WHEN 
    ((from_id  ='111111111' AND status='R') OR
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='S')) THEN 'D'
END) is not null
```

to avoid the error, cast the result of `CASE` into a `CHAR` like this:

```
CAST( (CASE
    WHEN 
    (from_id='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'S'
    WHEN 
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='A') THEN 'R'
    WHEN 
    ((from_id  ='111111111' AND status='R') OR
    (to_id  ='111111111' AND status='S')) THEN 'D'
END) AS CHAR) is not null
```

now it should work ok :)